# Access Neo4J shell via SSH?

Tags: ssh, neo4j

I installed Neo4J on a server of a hosting provider. The app that I run on it works fine. However, how would I access Neo4J shell? As I understand, I would do it through `http://www.myapp.com:PORT` normally (if I uncomment accept all internal connections in Neo4J config). But is there a way to access shell, admin and web interface without uncommenting those external connections line? Like directly from SSH for example? How?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a neo4j-shell command within the bin folder.  That will give you ssh access to running queries against neo4j

Comment: Thanks! And what about accessing their /browser and /webadmin? No way to do that without opening the port?

Comment: You can use ssh tunneling to forward requests - so if you are ssh'ing to a machine named 'graph' you would do:
ssh user@graph -L 5555:localhost:7474
which would take your local 5555 port, and forward to the machine named graph's (the above 'localhost' is what the machine you are ssh'ing into considers 'localhost') 7474 port, so you can open:
http://localhost:5555/browser
to access neo4j's browser.

Comment: you _may_ have to tweak the config of the neo4j browser to allow for external access - nothing huge, but something to keep in mind...